# WebSockets connection.send not function error

Tags: javascript

I have a Tornado client application which runs fine at its current state: In a simplified version, it has a structure like the folllowing code piece:

```
function comms(callback, newSession, connection) {
     if (newSession == true) {
          connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9022/id/01234');

          connection.onopen = function () {
               alert("connected");
               connection.send('hello world');
          };
     }

     connection.onerror = function (error) {
          alert('WebSocket Error ' + error);
     };


     connection.onmessage = function (e) {
          alert('>> message from Host: ' + e.data);
          callback(e.data, connection);
     }
}
```

I can connect, I can detect connection is on, I can send messages. I can receive messages. I can forward message via callback function and come back. No problem. All these are done via:

connection.onXXX event handler functions.

Now I want to send some unsolicited messages to server like the following:

```
function comms(callback, newSession, connection, request=false) {
     if (newSession == true) {
          connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9022/id/01234');

          connection.onopen = function () {
               alert("connected");
               connection.send('hello world');
          };
     }

     connection.onerror = function (error) {
          alert('WebSocket Error ' + error);
     };


     connection.onmessage = function (e) {
          alert('>> message from Host: ' + e.data);
          callback(e.data, connection);
     }

     if (request == true) {
          connection.send("request_msg");
     }
}
```

Although connection is open, I can not send such a request message. I receive:
"connection.send is not a function" error.

As I understand, somehow send request must be wrapped into a function, like other connection.onXXXX event handlers. But I do not have any such event or handler.

How can I send my message?

Comment: in what context are you calling this parent function? It could be that when you are calling the `connection.send` method before the connection object has actually been created or opened fully.

Comment: A python client executes HTML commands through the Tornado server. For the HTML client, messages comes from the server, and always the server sends the message first (except the first hello mesg which is actually initiated by the python client again). Browser responds to the messages depending on the request. Normally, this is a "PUSH" system. But now I want to send an unsolicited message from the HTML side. All the ws examples show that it is so easy: 1.) connect = new Websocket(ws://..., 2.) connect.send(msg). But send does not work outside connect.onXXX functions. That is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you would need to do this within an event.

**UPDATED:**

The `onmessage` event is what is fired on the server side, so any client processing can't be done in that event handler. I would suggest the client side functionality should be handled in a different function (not comms).

According to [this reference tutorial (an-introduction-to-websockets)](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/an-introduction-to-websockets), just call the send request from within the function from the client that requests the message.

Ie. as per the tutorials example, found [here](http://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/tHlBb), the request is called when the form is submitted / send message button is pressed. This is all wrapped in the `onload` function.

So you need some client side event or loop that can call the socket `connection(socket).send()` function, simply passing in text should be sufficient.

Does this help at all or does your application in it's 'complex' state achieve this already?

Comment: Yes, I did, and it is how the whole of the applicaton works. No problem with that. But that can happen only if there is a message from the server. I do not want that. I want to be able to send message when I want, as per this simple example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

Comment: I have found the problem. The connection parameter which I was sending back and forth via callback function was causing the problem. At the beginning comms function was in another external javascript and for some reason I could not get that connection shared among different functions just by making it global; and I had to pass it as parameter. Later, I joined those two external javascripts. Today I checked if I could getaway with using the global parameter back again. It worked, and it also solved the problem. Now the second script work OK, as expected.